# Google analytics to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets

I want to set up the final sheet on my google analytics to google spreadsheet reporting with a chart that has the productName dimension, with the 5 channelGrouping dimensions under each productName, on the Y-axis correlating to an X-axis with the itemRevenue metric for each productName.

It can be done static but I would like to run it dynamically.

Its either fixing the reporting to run dynamically on Google Spreadsheet or fixing the google analytics tagging to report all the productNames even if the itemRevenue is 0.

So if anyone has a solution to either one of the following questions it would be very much appreciated...

Question 1) Is there a way to get my ='reportsheet'!C16 for itemRevenue to change its row number when it shifts rows in the reportsheet since new data for productName, in the A column, will be coming into it by alphabetical order?

-or-

Question 2) Is there a way to run google analytics tagging to report in google spreadsheet all of the productNames even if the itemRevenue is 0?